# Apple Mach-O Linker Warning after xCode Update

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, swift3

After the latest update of xCode to `Version 8.3 (8E162)` I am getting warning at build time in my firebase project as below -

[image]

I am sorry couldn't copy paste the warning text here and couldn't type the lengthy warning as well. This was working fine without any problem before the update. This doesn't cause any problem since it is warning, however I seek help to resolve this warning.